# cannot trash malware NGPlayerSetup.dmg

Tags: malware

How do I delete this pesky dmg? I never asked for it and never uploaded or downloaded it. When I try to "Empty Trash" it is much to clever and says "it is in use."

Comment: For many files that refuse to go I use the Trash-It app, works for me and not affiliated.

Answer (score 1):

- Open Terminal
- type `cd .Trash` followed by <kbd>Return</kbd>
- type `rm NGPlayer` followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- the name should now auto-complete
- type <kbd>Return</kbd> to remove the file
- **reboot**

Please be aware that this will just remove the DMG from your system, it will not cleanout any malware which might already have gotten installed.

Comment: I was wondering if it was actually active & running from the dmg, rather than having been 'correctly' installed.

Comment: @Tetsujin So do I. But removing the DMG and rebooting should solve that.

Answer (score 1):

PC Risk has a page on its removal - [How to remove NG Player from Mac?](https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/13570-ng-player-adware-mac)

Ultimately they're trying to sell you their own software, but you can read their guide for free ;-)

You should also invest in a proper, recognised, full-time antivirus suite. Macs are not immune to infection, merely less-likely targets overall.

At minimum, I'd grab the free version of [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com) but ultimately I'd get something that scores well on a recognised test site like [AV-TEST](https://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/home-macos/)